# What's the meaning of the Rails version digits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, versions

How incompatible are rails versions with different version numbers? What's the meaning of these numbers?

For instance, from version 2.8.7 to 3.0.1, we may expect to have major incompatibility issues.

However, how incompatible would be versions 2.7.1 and 2.7.2 or 3.0.6 and 3.0.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [RubyGems Manual](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/7)

> Libraries change in 3 ways (well, more
> than 3, but stay focused here!).
>
> - The change may be an implementation detail only and have no effect on the
>   client software.
> - The change may add new features, but do so in a way that client
>   software written to an earlier version
>   is still compatible.
> - The change may change the public interface of the library in such a way
>   that old software is no longer
>   compatible.
>
> The RationalVersioningPolicy provides
> the following guidelines:
>
> Versions shall be represented by three
> non-negative integers, separated by
> periods (e.g. 3.1.4).
>
> The first
> integers is the ’’’major’’’ version
> number, the second integer is the
> ’’’minor’’’ version number, and the
> third integer is the ’’’build’’’
> number.
>
> - A category 1 change
>   (implementation detail) will increment
>   the build number.
> - A category 2 change
>   (backwards compatible) will increment
>   the minor version number and reset the
>   build number.
> - A category 3 change
>   (incompatible) will increment the
>   major build number and reset the minor
>   and build numbers. Any ’’public’’
>   release of a gem should have a
>   different version. Normally that means
>   incrementing the build number. This
>   means a developer can generate builds
>   all day long for himself, but as soon
>   as he/she makes a public release, the
>   version must be updated.
>
> That’s it. It’s not too difficult.

Additionaly. Who's interested in this answer may also be interested in the [Pessimistic Version Constraint](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74)

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, the bigger the change on the numbers, the bigger the changes in core.
So, 2.8.7 to 3.0.1 would be a major change because we go from Rails 2 to Rails 3(and is actually a very big change for real).

On the other hand, 2.7.1 to 2.7.2 would be some minor fixes.

And as DHH himself said, Rails is always willing to change its core 100% as long as great ideas arrive. So, you can imagine that going for 2 to 3 or from 3 to 4 most probably rings the bell of vast changes.

Comment: I am just wondering if a rails update in the second or third digits may break an application of mine. And I also wonder what's the meaning of these two different digits.

Comment: The meaning is what i describe. Severity of changes. I know it's probably difficult for you to undestand, but a small change on the core means that the lowest part is changed. Thus 3.0.1 to 3.0.2 is a subtle change. 3.1 to 3.2 is a bigger change. 3 to 4 is a major change. I can play it on piano if that helps you better.

Comment: And btw, applications do not break on version numbers, they break on changes. It's MORE THAN OBVIOUS that a more severe change can break your app anytime, always depending on what the actual change is.

Comment: @pedrorolo: LOL, you downvoted this answer? Why? Also: If you do TDD this should not be an issue. Run the test suite, use a newer Rails version, run the test suite again and see if something breaks. If you want to know the exact changes between versions, read the change logs. We can not guess if you use Rails feature XYZ that maybe behave differently in a newer version.

Comment: This answer is mere common sense and does not refer to the factual knowledge that exists about the topic. If everybody would always answer with common sense to questions, the earth would be flat and in the center of the universe. I don't want stackoverflow to be a place where the earth is flat.